# multiple websocket instances for chat application

Tags: django, websocket

I'm building a Django-Vue chat applicaton, I already builded the core functionallity of the app.

When the SideBar component is mounted a HTTP request is maded to get all rooms that the user is a participant, when some room is clicked a WebSocket instance is created on the Chat component.

My doubt is, if I send a message to that room but the others users are not connected in the same room (suposse that they are connected in other room) they will not receive the message right? So how I send him a notification about the new message? like Whatsapp sidebar notifications.

I was thinking in create two WebSocket connections, one on the SideBar that will be the user endpoint (`ws:127.0.0.1:8000/chat/$Username`) and other for the actually chat room (`ws:127.0.0.1:8000/chat/$ChatId`), is that a good approach?

My django models =>

```
from django.db import models
from account.models import CustomUser

class Message(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='messages')
    message = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'message from {self.sender.username}'

class Chat(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=24)
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser, blank=True)
    messages = models.ManyToManyField(Message, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use WSS as a transport layer but implement your own logic protocol.

Of course, you can utilize several connections, but it's redundant.
Let's use something like "events".
For example, for a user connected to a chat room, you can send "connection" event:

```js
{
    "event": "connection",
    "user": {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "Foo",
        ...
    }
}
```

You can handle such an event with a simple approach:

```py
if event == "connection":
    ...
elif event == "exit":
elif event == "message":
...
```

And the same approach but on the client-side with JS code.

So you can handle only one connection both for the Vue app and for Django one.

Comment: In the solution that you put, each user will be connected to wich websocket endpoint? `chat/$USERNAME`? Should I duplicate the `self.channel_layer.group_send` to send to my username and the target username? I am really lost the flow.

Comment: Sure, you can make a connection pool to store a connection state with every user. Personally me, I don't use Django to create WS servers in my projects. There are 2 reasons: Django (with DRF) is cool as API, powerful ORM, and admin; as an async framework I'm using Starlette.io, it has built-in WS support and async by design https://www.starlette.io/websockets/ and you can easily run it via the same infrastructure (with some additions) So, you can make 2 services: API with DB and ORM on Django; WS service. Additional pros - in your stack you will have a second tool for true async things.

Comment: Channels can't do what Starlette do? should I change? All data on in site are manipulated using DRF.

Comment: Of course, you can use the Channels framework, but if you want to utilize the microservice approach it will be comfortable to make a standalone WS service. You need to use DRF API via HTTP. So DRF will be used in both approaches. Starlette is much simple than Channels layers and it will add the additional framework to your stack for simple services.